# Is it possible to checkout git branch using svn?

Tags: git, svn

I have a git repository that needs to be checked out on a server. I cannot install git on this server. But can is already present on it.

Is there any option by which I can checkout git branch using svn?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can do nothing with Git, using any SVN-client